# How to find the location of a macro's use between crates?

Tags: debugging, macros, rust

When a macro causes a panic (directly or indirectly) between crates, the line of code from which the macro is used isn't included in the back-trace.

This makes it impossible to know which use of the macro caused the panic.

Meaning, if you have a macro used in many places, you can't find which line of code to focus on.

I ran into this problem because my tests are in a separate directly, and use the code they tests as a crate.

[Git repository](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/test_42277783_report/tree/master) for the example below.

`tests/tests.rs`

```
extern crate test_macro;
#[test]
fn main() {
    let file: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    test_macro::decode_main(&*file).unwrap();
}
```

`src/lib.rs`

```
use ::std::io;

macro_rules! read_exact {
    ($f:expr, $r:expr) => {
        io::Read::read_exact($f, $r).unwrap()
    }
}

fn decode_blocks<R: io::Read>(mut file: R) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let mut bhead: [u8; 320] = [0; 320];
    read_exact!(&mut file, &mut bhead);  // <-- this line isn't in the backtrace
    Ok(())
}

pub fn decode_main<R: io::Read>(mut file: R) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    decode_blocks(file)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Calling:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo test
```

Gives the backtrace:

```
                        at /buildslave/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-linux/build/src/libcore/result.rs:737
  11:     0x562061ffd7da - test_macro::decode_blocks::h391253710f990761
                        at /src/test_macro/src/lib.rs:5
  12:     0x562061ffd5ca - test_macro::decode_main::h43b3b33b47640ea4
                        at /src/test_macro/src/lib.rs:16
  13:     0x562061fff1ad - tests::main::hc17f25ef21544d0b
                        at /src/test_macro/tests/tests.rs:5
  14:     0x56206200d54e - <F as test::FnBox<T>>::call_box::h04563d623b7ebdf9
```

Notice line 11 isn't included.

---

Using Rust stable 1.15. Reported this as bug [#39894](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39894).

Comment: Sounds like a bug...

Comment: Which version of the compiler?

Comment: Works for me ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d967ab54cef2fc55e22f1e1546b8dcee&version=stable&backtrace=1))

Comment: @Chris Emerson, confirmed it works in simple case.... and re-confirmed it fails in a more complex test-case, this will take some time to simplify.

Comment: Update, this is only happening between crates. Edited question and included working example and git repo.